# Forcing edittext to only accept values of: numbers, decimals, plus, and minus signs

Tags: android, android-edittext

this is my xml code

---

```
              <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etSPHr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/myedittext"
                    android:digits="0123456789.+-"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/etCYLr"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" >
```

---

the problem is my keyboard doesnt let me use the plus sign its disabled

Comment: numberDecimal as inputype will not allow to enter '+' or '-'

Comment: i changed it to numberDecimal|numberSigned but the plus sign is disabled on the keyboard any hints ?

Comment: if its not negative, then its obvious positive..

Comment: We are here to help if you are unable to solve your issue, but you should show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

should work.

Comment: i did that but the plus sign is not enabled i cant use it !!!! any idea

Comment: The `+` sign will never be enabled with any of the input type flags. `numberSigned` gives you the `-`. The `+` sign is implied if it isn't there. Consider using a TextWatcher and then filter the results if you absolutely need the `+`.

Comment: can u show me any code doing so plz

Comment: @HuMax Try something yourself. Changes are that if I give you the code, you'd have more issues since you haven't worked with it and so, don't have a full understanding of it. Are you trying to make an equation parser and so, really need the `+`?

Comment: the values i want to use are +2.50   or -3.30

Comment: Like @Mitesh and I keep saying, just `2.50` *implies* `+2.50`. Users can be quite smart with basic things like this.