# Why does my EditText box allow usage of plus sign

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

This is actually part of my homework and my friends did similar thing but the problem occurs only for me. this is my xml code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:id="@+id/sheepNumBox"/>
```

For some reason I can type '+' into the EditText box while it shouldn't, any ideas why?

Comment: obviously, because '+' is a number sign ...

Comment: From reading answers to other questions on this site I understood it shouldn't be enabled. also my friends have almost the same xml code and only mine allows '+'.

Comment: then you understand it wrong ... do not trust android:inputType ... AFAIK it is only a hint for keyboard(as you know android users can use custom keyboards) not a filter ... so it depends on keyboard used by user and some keyboards implementation can take it seriously and some not ...

Comment: This makes sense but it still doesn't explain why this occurs only for me out of many people taking the course. Also look at the comments to the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488060/forcing-edittext-to-only-accept-values-of-numbers-decimals-plus-and-minus-si
they also don't go along your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code..

```
  final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.sheepNumBox);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (text.contains("+")) {
                text.replace("+", "");
                editText.settext(text);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: first of all even if this solution works I wanted to know what could be the reason it was enabled in the first place while it shouldn't.
Secondly this doesn't work because you didn't change the actual text in the edittext and if you did it might cause an infinite loop (which can be avoided but anyway this is not what I am looking for).

Comment: The updated code causes an infinite loop and a stack overflow.

Comment: That's where I added it. you forget that when you use `setText()` the function `onTextChanged()` is called again.

Comment: No it won't be called because the next time the text wont have plus sign and hence won't set text again coz of if condition!

Comment: I copied this exact code and got stackOverflowException from this exact call.

Comment: by the way it worked when moved to afterTextChanged();

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:id="@+id/sheepNumBox"/>
```

Comment: this is not an option because I need to be able to type in negative numbers also. I want it to remain the same but without being able to type in '+'. from reading other questions on this site this shouldn't be enabled by default and i don't know why it is enabled on my app.